# how do i mock the a static method that provides an instance of the class being mocked with JMockit?

Tags: java, unit-testing, static, java-6, jmockit

I'm trying to mock a singleton class (SessionDataManager) where I get an instance by calling the static getInstance() method but all attempts seem to return null.

I've tried

```
    @Mocked SessionDataManager sessionDataManager;
```

or

```
        new MockUp<SessionDataManager>(){
            @Mock
            public SessionDataManager getInstance(Invocation invocation) {

                return invocation.getInvokedInstance(); 
            }
        };
```

I get the same result = null;

Can anyone suggestion a solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest having a look at the [documentation](http://jmockit.org/tutorial.html), but here are two complete example tests:

```
public final class ExampleTest {
    public static final class SessionDataManager {
        private static final SessionDataManager instance = new SessionDataManager();
        public static SessionDataManager getInstance() { return instance; }
        public void doSomething() { throw new UnsupportedOperationException("to do"); }
    }

    @Test
    public void mockingASingleton(@Mocked SessionDataManager mockInstance) {
        SessionDataManager singletonInstance = SessionDataManager.getInstance();

        assertSame(mockInstance, singletonInstance);
        singletonInstance.doSomething(); // mocked, won't throw
    }

    @Test
    public void mockingASingletonWithAMockUp() {
        new MockUp<SessionDataManager>() {
            // no point in having a @Mock getInstance() here
            @Mock void doSomething() { /* whatever */ }
        };

        SessionDataManager singletonInstance = SessionDataManager.getInstance();
        singletonInstance.doSomething(); // redirects to the @Mock method, won't throw
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Expectations' class:

```
new Expectations() {

    Singleton singleton;
    {
        Singleton.getInstance(); returns(singleton);
        singleton.valueFromSingleton(); returns(1);
    }
};

Entity entity = new Entity();
assertEquals(1, entity.valueFromEntity());
```

Comment: Thank you https://stackoverflow.com/users/6231002/aura you help is greatly appreciated. I'm still getting a Null pointer exception at the declaration of the Expectations.

Comment: You are welcome. If you solved the problem, can you please accept the answer by clicking on the tick to the left of the answer? Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/6231002/aura I've tried using the code exactly how you provided but i'm still getting the Null pointer exception